# org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type Model

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, localdatetime

This is repository method, which as you will see select columns from UserDetail Entity Table by created_date, but I have getting error When I type in swagger this value 2021-10-14 23:16:31

```
@Query(value = "SELECT usd.phoneNumber,usd.textMessage FROM UserDetail entity usd WHERE usd.created_date=:createdDate", nativeQuery = true)
    UserDetail findByCreatedDate(LocalDateTime createdDate);
```

I try to type parametr String format in service layer and convert to LocalDate time like following code:

```
 @Override
    public UserDetail findByCreatedDateWhenUserTypeOwnInfo(String createdDate) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(createdDate, formatter);
        return this.userDetailRepository.findByCreatedDate(dateTime);
    }
```

I have getting this error:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [az.expressbank.expressbankproject.data.model.UserDetail]
```

How to solve this problem>?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT * FROM UserDetail ...`?

Comment: What do you mean I do not understand you.

Comment: If you change the query to `SELECT * FROM UserDetail ...`, does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using "named parameters" so looks like you need to add a @Param to your query. like this:

```
UserDetail findByCreatedDate(@Param("createdDate") LocalDateTime createdDate);
```

Comment: I do this, but right now I am getting this error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.test.userdetail' doesn't exist, but all is true.

Comment: Is the error exactly like that?  with lowercase name for the table ?   How is your real table named?